# Initializing an array in Hack Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

What is the syntax for declaring initialized data, such as:

- initializing a global array in the hack assembly language?

ex. int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

- initializing a string literal?

"hello world\n"

Comment: Good question.  I've searched around and cannot find any example code for, say, "hello world", which, if found, might tell us how the string ("hello world") is stored and declared in their assembly language.  All the assembly language examples that I've seen are of machine code, not initialized data.  Of course we can declare code that stores into data memory, but that seems an awfully awkward way to create initialized strings and arrays.

Comment: Near as I can tell, the jack compiler generates code to construct string literals dynamically, allocating heap space, and then building them by appending one character at a time.  So, individual character values are stored in individual machine code instructions and reassembled into a string in the heap using function calls like `string.new` and `string.append`.  This suggests that maybe it is not possible to load the initial state of RAM along with the program (in ROM).

Comment: You can build an integer array of initial values the same way, by writing  initial values of each individual array element using constants encoded in code sequences followed by appropriate store instructions, and perhaps simplify by hard coding the address of the array in RAM instead of using heap allocation.

Comment: And lastly, you can preload values into RAM using script, but that is not part of the assembly language, rather it is part of the testing system to allow different scripts to establish initial conditions and examine final conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hack assembly language has no facility for doing this directly, since it only assembles program instructions, and the program memory is read-only and not readable by Hack machine instructions, other than the degenerate case of the load constant operation.

Thus, what you have to do is write code that initializes your ram, using a sequence of load constant/store operations. This is made a little more tricky because you can only load 15-bit constants.

When I was faced with this issue I wrote a python script to generate the assembly code I needed. Here is a python code snippet that generates code to store an arbitrary value "word" into the memory location "base" that may prove helpful to you.

```
if word >= 32768:
    if word == 65535:
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(base) + "\t\t// " + str(word)
        print "\tM = -1"
    else:
        print "\tD = -1\t\t// " + str(word)
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(65535-word)
        print "\tD = D - A"
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(base)
        print "\tM = D"
else:
    if word == 0:
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(base) + "\t\t// " + str(word)
        print "\tM = 0"
    else:
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(word) + "\t\t// " + str(word)
        print "\tD = A"
        print "\t@" + "{:05}".format(base)
        print "\tM = D"

base += 1
```